# GWTBootstrap row appears as a column instead of a row

Tags: html, css, gwtbootstrap3

I am just starting to use bootstrap to convert an existing GWT project. In the following code my first img, h3 and second img are in a single column (one under the other) instead in a single row (next to each other).

```
<div id="login"  class="container-fluid" style="background-repeat: repeat; background-image: url('body-bg.jpg'); display:flex;">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img class="myimg" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="logo.png" style="width: 130px;" />
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <h3> Welcome to the Award Tracker login page. </h3>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
                <img class="myimg" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="1stER_icon_256.png" style="width: 130px;" />
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /row -->

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <form class="form-signin">
                    <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
                    <input id="accountName" type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address">
                    <input id="enterPassword" type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password">
                    <button id="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- /row -->

    </div> <!-- /container -->
```

How do I get my first row to be a row instead of a column please?

Also, is there a way to make the img shrink as I shrink the page?

I used http://www.layoutit.com/build to create this and made very few changes. Is there a good free product I can download as my internet is very very slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

check the code below, two things

1st: added `display:flex;` to your header container (note: flex are not supported by old IE etc... for more info check here make sure you can use it http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox).

2nd: added css to make img response

3rd: left img align to left, right img align to right

```
.myimg {
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

hope it helps =D

```css
.myheader {
  display: flex;
}

.myimg {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}

.pull-right {
  text-align: right;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<div id="login" class="container-fluid" style="background-repeat: repeat; background-image: url('body-bg.jpg');">

  <div class="row myheader">
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img class="myimg" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="logo.png" />
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h3> Welcome to the Award Tracker login page. </h3>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <img class="myimg  pull-right" alt="Bootstrap Image Preview" src="1stER_icon_256.png" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /row -->

  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
      <form class="form-signin">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign in</h2>
        <input id="accountName" type="text" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Email address">
        <input id="enterPassword" type="password" class="input-block-level" placeholder="Password">
        <button id="submit" class="btn btn-large btn-primary" type="submit">Sign in</button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- /row -->

</div>
<!-- /container -->
```

Comment: Hi Daniel, That works; however, the line is aligned to the left instead of centred. I would like the first image on the left, the text in the centre and the second image on the right please.

Comment: Tried this and no change. I have made a small changed to your code - width: 130px; instead of width: 100%; Tried both and still aligned left. It is "image-text-image" and I want "image---------------text---------------image".

Comment: @Glyn what browser and version do you use? cus might not support display:flex . I updated here https://jsfiddle.net/dalinhuang/vdp1ztqf/

Comment: Hi @Daniel H, I missed putting the <script, <link and <script lines in. It now works.

Comment: @Glyn ohh, great =D